# I didnt received funds into my wallet

Tags: wallet, funds

Funds were sent from another wallet to my wallet, but i didnt received the funds, please help

Comment: Which wallet sent, and which wallet received?

Comment: You must be more specific to indicate which wallet you use to receive the transaction you can also see in the block browser the address that you have used

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible explanations and many possible ways to investigate

#### Possible causes

- The sender mis-typed the receiving address. This is hard to do if the
  sender scanned a QR code. There are usually checksums built in that
  make it hard to get a mis-typed address accepted. Nevertheless it is
  possible
- You gave the sender a different address than the one you think you did.
  This can happen as many wallets issue a different receiving address
  for each transaction.
- You accidentally gave the sender the address of a wallet that uses
  a different crypto-currency than the crypto-currency the sender sent.
  This is fairly common. It is arguably too easy to confuse Bitcoin cash
  for Bitcoin.
- The sender didn't pay a sufficient mining fee
- Your wallet is no longer synchronising
- You didn't wait long enough
- Fraud

If you are using a web-wallet where you depend on a third party, there are also a lot of other ways in which things can go wrong. Especially if the
provider of the service aggregates transactions. (This is one reason I would prefer to use a standalone wallet).

#### Ways to investigate.

- Go to a [blockchain explorer](https://google.com/search?q=blockchain+explorer) website and enter the transaction-ID.
  Do the same for the receiving address. Check that your transaction appears.
  Check that everything is as you would expect it to be.
- Re-check the address you used, letter by letter. re-check the currency.
- If your wallet is hosted by a third party, raise the issue with their
  customer support service.